# Java Boolean Assignment Confusion

Tags: java

I am a bit confused at the following java code. First it appears to assign an assignment- statement to a boolean variable...`boolean bvalue = (b = true)` instead of true or false.

Then the output is `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `TRUE`.  The third and final TRUE of the output has me baffled since bvalue evaluates to true for the first if-conditional. I don't see any code that explicitly assigns false to bvalue.  Any helpful comments would be greatly appreciated.

```
boolean b;
boolean bvalue = (b = true);

if (bvalue)
    System.out.println("TRUE");
else
    System.out.println("FALSE");

if (bvalue = false)
    System.out.println("TRUE");
else
    System.out.println("FALSE");

if (bvalue == false)
    System.out.println("TRUE");
else
    System.out.println("FALSE");
```

Comment: FYI, use `if (!bvalue)` rather than `if (bvalue == false)`.

Answer (score 4):

`=` is the assignement operator. It returns assigned value. So code

```
if (bvalue = false) 
System.out.println("TRUE");
else System.out.println("FALSE");
```

is equivalent to

```
bvalue = false;
if (bvalue) 
System.out.println("TRUE");
else System.out.println("FALSE");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me break it down for you:

```
boolean b;
boolean bvalue = (b = true);
```

the assignment operator, =, also have a return value and it's the value of the assignment, so both b and bvalue gets assigned true.

```
if (bvalue) 
System.out.println("TRUE");
else System.out.println("FALSE");
```

since bvalue is true, this prints "TRUE".

```
if (bvalue = false) 
System.out.println("TRUE");
else System.out.println("FALSE");
```

here you use the assignment operator instead of the comparison one, = vs ==, so bvalue is assigned false, and that is also returned to the if statement, making it take the else path and print "FALSE".

```
if (bvalue == false) 
System.out.println("TRUE");
else System.out.println("FALSE");
```

here you compare bvalue, which is false, with false, and that's a true statement, so "TRUE" gets printed.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification.  This has been very helpful.

Comment: @user2578561 please choose one of the answers as the accepted answer if you are satisfied with the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Discription:-

```
    boolean b;
        boolean bvalue = (b = true);    //firstly true assigned to b by (b=true) then b assigned to bvalue (bval=true)
        if (bvalue) // check if  bvalue = true & succeed 
        System.out.println("TRUE");  // printed
        else System.out.println("FALSE");

        if (bvalue = false) // firstly assign false to bvalue then if executes 
        System.out.println("TRUE");
        else System.out.println("FALSE"); // printed as bvalue is false

        if (bvalue == false)  // check if bvalue is false & success
        System.out.println("TRUE"); //printed as bvalue is false
        else System.out.println("FALSE");
```

output:-
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE